# Splitting a data set into multiple parts

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

**The Problem**

I am trying to split a data set into multiple parts - thanks to help in the past, this has been done before into 2 parts, but I would like to extend this functionality into multiple parts (though the example uses 3). I suspect my problem is how I've used `SplitBy`.

Here I am intending to split the graph into multiple parts and draw a dashed line on the graph joining the last and first point of each part. And be able to still calculate average etc.

Additionally the average current figure seems to display as a fraction rather than a decimal - I tried `NumberForm` to fix it but it made no change.

**The Code**

```
dataSet = {{1000, 5}, {1500, 10}, {2000, 12}, {3000, 17}, {3601, 
    31}, {4010, 40}, 4050, 44};

{set[1], set[2], set[3]} = 
  SplitBy[dataSet, #[[1]] < 1850 & , #[[2]] > 1850 & < 
     3200 &, #[[3]] > 3200 &];
avgCurrent = 
  Integrate[
    Interpolation[dataSet, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
     dataSet[[1, 1]], dataSet[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
     dataSet[[{-1, 1}, 1]]);
maxCurrent = MaximalBy[dataSet, Last][[1, 2]];
noPoints = Length[dataSet];
lifeTime = dataSet[[-1, 1]];
ListLinePlot[{set[1], set[2], set[3]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6000}, {0, 25}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.85], 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{1500, 10`}, {2000, 12`}}]}, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{3000, 17`}, {3601, 31`}}]}, {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
    Point[dataSet]}, 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.85, .9}]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Element (Cathode ?) - Current Yield", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Cathode ? - Element"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.85, 0.5}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {850, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

**The Output (The Relevant Bit - I think)**

A series of errors, leading with...

Part::partw: Part 2 of #1 does not exist.
SplitBy::argt: SplitBy called with 3 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you explain how you want to spit the data?

Comment: Look up "SplitBy" in the help you are using it the wrong way.

Comment: I would like to split the data so that each set[] is joined with a solid line on the graph, and a dotted line between sets. (As due to it being a new day, it represents an artificial increase)

Comment: I have looked at the 'SplitBy' page but am still unsure what I'm doing wrong. I have admittedly always found it hard to understand the documentation. I have changed the code based on what I thought the documentation is expecting, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is a typo in the definition of `dataSet`, that the last two elements should be curl-bracketed:

```
dataSet = {{1000, 5}, {1500, 10}, {2000, 12}, {3000, 17}, {3601, 
    31}, {4010, 40}, {4050, 44}};
```

Then I spit by hand:

```
set[1] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; x < 1850];
set[2] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; 1850 < x < 3200];
set[3] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; x > 3200];
```

To get a decimal form of `avgCurrent` I use `N` in combination with `SetPrecision` to obtain the needed digital points:

```
avgCurrent = 
 Integrate[
   Interpolation[dataSet, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
    dataSet[[1, 1]], dataSet[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
    dataSet[[{-1, 1}, 1]])//N//SetPrecision[#,3]&
(* 17.8 *)
```

Finally I changed the `PlotRange` to `{{0, 6000}, {0, 50}}` because the maximal `y` value in `dataSet` is `44`.

The rest of the code works for me and I got this plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect.